# Fourier series: if $f$ is $C^\infty$ then $f(x) = s_n(x) + o(1/n^k) $ as $n\to \infty$.

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-series

Suppose $f$ is differentiable any number of times and is $2\pi$-periodical. Let $k\in \mathbb{N}$. Show that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}n^k|f(x)-s_n(x)|= 0$$
i.e that $f(x)=s_n(x)+o(1/n^k)$ as $n\to \infty$. The $s_n$ are the $n$th Fourier partial sums.

Intuitively I would like to show this using an argument along the following lines:
\begin{align*}
s_n(x) - f(x) &= \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}[f(x+y)-f(x)]D_n(y)dy\\
&= \int_{\delta\leq |y| \leq \pi}[f(x+y)-f(x)]D_n(y)dy+\int_{0\leq |y|\leq \delta}[f(x+y)-f(x)]D_n(y)dy\\
&\approx 0 +  \int_{0\leq |y|\leq \delta}o\Big(\dfrac{1}{n^k} \Big)D_n(y)dy
\end{align*}
as $n\to\infty$, for some $\delta>0$ small enough (since $f$ is differentiable). However, this seems hard to make rigorous, and having both sides depend on $n$ makes me hesitant to use this little-o notation. Some hints/solutions would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you forgot to suppose $f$ is $2\pi$-periodical.

Comment: @88888888 True. I've edited the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f=\sum_n c_n(f) e^{inx}$ and $(in)^{k+2} c_n(f)= c_n(f^{(k+2)})$ is bounded by $\|f^{(k+2)}\|_{L^1[0,2\pi]}$ thus $$|\sum_{|n|> N} c_n(f)e^{inx}|\le N^{-k-1}\|f^{(k+2)}\|_{L^1[0,2\pi]}$$

Comment: could you explain how you got the last inequality? It looks like it says that the tail of the series after $N$ is smaller than the first $N$ terms, but I don't see why this is true.

Comment: $|\sum_{|n|> N} c_n(f)e^{inx}|\le \sum_{|n|>N} n^{-k-2} C\le 2C N^{-k-1}$